# how to increase docker build's volume size

Tags: docker

One of my steps in `Dockerfile` requires more than 10G space on disk. It really does. However, all the intermediate containers in `docker build` are created with 10G volumes.

What I did:

- started `dockerd` with `--storage-opt dm.basesize=25G` (`docker info` says: `Base Device Size: 26.84 GB`)
- disabled cache while building
- re-pulled the base images
- stopped docker, removed everything from the docker directory, and started it again

It's no good: `df -h` in an intermediate container still shows a `10G` disk, and `docker inspect` of it shows `"DeviceSize": "10737418240"`.

What have I missed? How do I increase the base volume size?

Comment: It can help: http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/

Comment: @molivier but... that's exactly what I did, didn't I?

Comment: I mean this part: "All new containers would not have the increased rootfs size. As we saw above even after restarting the daemon with the new base device size (–storage-opt dm.basesize=20G), we would still need to update all the existing images in order for new containers to reap benefits of this new size."

Comment: From documentation : "This value affects the system-wide “base” empty filesystem that may already be initialized and inherited by pulled images". Typically, a change to this value requires additional steps to take effect: `$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo service docker start$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo service docker start`

Comment: A look into your Dockerfile would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To grant containers access to more space, we need to take care of two things:

1. Make sure that dockerd is started with: `--storage-opt dm.basesize=25G`
2. Make sure that we pull a clean version of the image **after** increasing the basesize.

**Example:**

1. Start dockerd with:

   ```
   --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G
   ```
2. **Restart** docker daemon
3. Checking the container size here will display the older value of 10G:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm ubuntu:xenial df -h
   ```
4. **Delete** the image and **repull** it

   ```
   docker rmi ubuntu:xenial
   docker pull ubuntu:xenial
   ```
5. Confirm changes took place with the expected value of 25G:

   ```
   docker run -it --rm ubuntu:xenial df -h
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this problem has been resolved in the meantime or not. But if anyone stumbles across this in 2019 (or possibly later), the clean solution to this kind of problems is to switch to another storage backend.

To do this, copy all keepworthy Docker data to a safe location. Stop the Docker daemon. Delete `/var/lib/docker` (or move it away to allow a rollback if anything goes wrong). Then re-create an empty `/var/lib/docker` and add file `daemon.json` with the following content

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Then, restart the Docker daemon and the artificial 10G limit is gone.

See the documentation for further details: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

In case there is really no way around the `DeviceSize` thing, I remember once creating it by hand (in the sense of a `dd` command with the expected device size) and starting the Docker daemon afterwards. However, as of today, necessity for doing this should be gone.

Comment: Just so everybody knows, location of daemon.json is:

/etc/docker/daemon.json

and not in /var/lib/docker in 2024