# No disk space left on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS instance (EC2). I created to run Jupyter Notebook to test. And suddenly the space ran out, see the result below:

```
root@ip-172-31-14-181:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            992M     0  992M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M   21M  180M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       15G   15G   55M 100% /
tmpfs          1000M  2.5M  997M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             15G   15G   55M 100% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3a5473a...
none             15G   15G   55M 100% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d0f29d3...
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/c501847.../shm
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/851f091.../shm
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

How can I solve this kind of problem?

I was not very clear on the question. In fact, the disk is full but I can't find why it is full. Through research I managed to add only 10 GB of occupied space.
Furthermore, it is a docker to run Jupyter remotely, and it doesn't even have 500Mb of Jupiter file there ...
Would there be any way to understand what made 5Gb disappear? Or how to review the sizes of folders and files?

Comment: You're out of disk space.  We have no idea why but see [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html) and then [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).  That will give you more space but if you run out again you'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: By deleting stuff or growing the volume.

Comment: I was not very clear on the question. In fact, the disk is full but I can't find why it is full. Through research I managed to add only 10 GB of occupied space.
Furthermore, it is a docker to run Jupyter remotely, and it doesn't even have 500Mb of Jupiter file there ...
Would there be any way to understand what made 5Gb disappear? Or how to review the sizes of folders and files?

Answer (score 1):

Those look like mostly docker related stuff, like volumes. Stop the containers, remove ones you don't need and clean up docker volumes and layers

Answer (score 1):

seems like a problem with docker volume rather than EC2 problem as shown in df-h output:

```
none             15G   15G   55M 100% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3a5473a...
none             15G   15G   55M 100% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/d0f29d3...
```

try to run the command inside the container to determine why the disk is full,
or increase the docker volume size:
[how to increase docker build's volume size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159916/how-to-increase-docker-builds-volume-size)
you can try to clean up the images you do not need in docker